# Google maps not working on Android emulator behind proxy

Tags: android, google-maps, proxy, android-emulator

We have a proxy server running in our institute which requires authentication. While I can run my browser in the emulator after providing the proxy settings, I cannot run any other application which requires internet connection. I am developing an app. and I would like to know if there is a way to provide proxy settings ( for my app, or all apps ) so that I can get google maps working. I know that there was a bug, but is that fixed by now or is there some hack which tries to overcome that problem? It would be of great help even if I can get a local solution i.e access google maps from my app, not necessary that all apps which require an internet connection run.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? Something like [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) could help..

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest Android SDK installed and after I provided -http-proxy switch with valid proxy address for emulator.exe, Google Maps started to work without problemы. Haven't tried to use MapView in my own app though. May be check that you specified proxy correctly and see TCP connections for emulator.exe?

Comment: i provided the proxy settings through wireless and networks -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names, can you describe how see TCP connections and that -http-proxy switch command in detail.

Comment: You have to provide that switch in emulator command line. See [Using the Emulator with a Proxy](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#proxy). To see TCP connection you may use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)